# Guessing sum of random sub set of length x from one set

Tags: probability

Given a known Set x . 
Given a know size y. 
User choose a random subset from x of size y. 
We need to guess the sum of the new subset. 
both x and y are less then 5000. 
After searching on net this problem seem to  be related like **Variance** (one example is :Fair dice ).

But I am not able to find the solution for this problem. 
As number can't be repeated in the set. 
So what will the formula for this problem ?

Comment: The set x is an arbitrary set of numbers?  "Length" means "size"? I dont understand what has this to do with "Variance", and why you are looking for a "formula"...

Comment: @Vivek: there are some details need to be known about your problem.   If $x$ finite, countable or uncountable (maybe a subset of set of reals) - since the random choice depends on it very much? Btw, for the *guess* about the sum of elements in the random set, you better use expectation or the confidence interval.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: "So what will the formula for this problem ?" Can you clearly describe what the problem is? Currently the question is not at all readable.

Comment: The way I understand it: you have a set consisting of the first X natural numbers. You pick a random subset of Y elements from the set. The question is asking how to guess the sum of the numbers in the subset. Is that right?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: One possible guess would be the expected value, which is $y$ times the average of the values of the elements of $x$.

Comment: @Henry but how that would be ?

Comment: Let $A$ be a set $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ of numbers.  We choose at random a subset $B$ of $A$, such that $B$ has $m$ elements. Then the expected value of the sum of the numbers in $B$ is $(m/n)\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$.

Comment: One can generalize somewhat by allowing some of the $a_i$ to be equal.  The wording has to be changed, but the answer doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be a set of $n$ real numbers.  We choose at random an $m$-element subset $A$ of $B$.  We want to know the expected value (mean) of the sum of the chosen numbers.

Let $B=\{b_1,b_2,\dots, b_n\}$.  Imagine that the choosing is done *sequentially*.
Let the random variable $X_i$ be the $i$-th number chosen, and let 
$$X=\sum_{i=1}^m X_i.$$
Then $X$ is the sum of the chosen numbers, and we want to find $E(X)$, the expected value of this sum.  For *any* random variables $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_m$ we have
$$E\left(\sum_{i=1}^m X_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^m E(X_i).$$
Now we need to compute $E(X_i)$.  But $X_i$ takes on the values $b_1, b_2,\dots, b_n$, each with probability $1/n$. It follows that 
$$E(X_i)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i}{n},$$
and therefore
$$E(X)=\frac{m}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nb_i.$$

**Comments**:

$1$. The OP specified that the numbers chosen are *distinct*.  In standard terminology, this means that the choosing is done *without replacement*.  The above argument does not depend on whether the choosing is done with replacement or without replacement: the answer under each assumption is the same.

$2$. In an answer to one of the comments, the OP seemed to say that the set $B$ consists of the first $n$ positive integers, though that wasn't entirely clear.  If $B=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, then 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\quad\text{and therefore}\quad E(X)=\frac{m(n+1)}{2}.$$

$3$. The same argument goes through if $B$ is a *multiset* (some of the $b_i$ are allowed to be equal), and $A$ is a (multi)subset of $B$.

$4$. As Yuval Filmus has pointed out in a comment, we can also find the variance of $X$ by an argument that exploits the linearity of expectation.

Answer (score 0):

The expected value will be indeed better estimation for the sum, while the variance corresponds to the error of this estimation. Let me denote $x = \{x_1,...,x_n\}$. To model the random choice you should construct a probability space and there are several possibilities to do it.

The one is to pick up a random combination $s = \{s_1,...,s_y\}\subset x$ of $y$ elements from $x$. E.g. $s_1 = x_2,s_2 = x_3,s_3=x_4$ and so on. Let $S$ denote the set of all possible such combinations. Since numbers cannot repeat, $S$ has $C^y_n$ elements. To model a random choice you can assume that each combination has the same probability which is 
$$p(n,y) = \displaystyle{\frac{1}{C^y_n}}.$$

The formula for the expectation of the sum will be 
$$
E = p(n,y)\sum\limits_{s\in S}\sum\limits_{i=1}^ys_i
$$
and for the variance
$$
V = p(n,y)\sum\limits_{s\in S}\left(E-\sum\limits_{i=1}^ys_i\right)^2.
$$

Although these formulas look weird, unfortunately if you don't have any special information about $x$ (e.g. $x  =1,2,...,n$) then I believe you should deal with all possbile combinations. If you $x$ has a nice structure, then there can be nice formulas for $E$ and $V$.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, using linearity of expectation it's easy to compute E. You can compute V the same way, with perhaps a few more lines of computation.

Comment: @Proteus: To add detail to the comment by Yuval Filmus, do the picking sequentially, let random variable $X_i$ be the number picked on the $i$-th trial, and let $X=\sum_1^m X_i$. Then $E(X)=E(\sum_1^m X_i)=\sum_1^m E(X_i)$. Independence is *not* required. And if the possible values are $a_1,\dots,a_n$, then $E(X_i)=(1/n)\sum_1^n a_i$.  Expectation is great, we often need very little information to compute it. In particular, we do not need the probability distribution of the sum.

Comment: @Andre: oh yeah, I missed it. Maybe you post these comments as an answer - seems that OP was wondering about it. Then I'll delete mine.

Comment: There is no need to delete.  Just modify your absolute assertion that nothing further can be done.  You have given a valid expression for the answer.